# How to make HTML Canvas to use the Same X & Y of the mouse position in other resolution screen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My canvas game has onclick buttons which redirecting to another menu.
When opening my Canvas in another resolution monitor all the X & Y changed and nothing is working.

Is there a way to block the Canvas from getting affect from different monitors?

Answer (score -1):

Use `e.offsetX` and `e.offsetY`  to get the mouse coordinates on the canvas:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    c = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    console.log(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
}
```

Comment: Could the person that downvoted me please tell me why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it. That said, this code works, I really don't see the reason for a downvote.

Comment: Hi Cerebrus,Thanks for your quick response but it's not working.
Any other idea?

Comment: @user2007221: what is not working? are you getting any errors?

Comment: Simply the X's and Y's coordinates changing to unexistable numbers.
Such as X - -24 y- 1006

My canvas Width is 800 and Height is 500.

So you can see it's not making sense

Comment: That's weird. can you try `clientX / clientY` instead?

Comment: Instead of offsetX & IfffsetY ?

Comment: @user2007221: Instead of those, yes.

Comment: @user2007221: What browser are you using?